# div slide using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using this jQyery code to slide div's that contains street camera streams.

```
  jQuery(function () {
var $els = $('div[id^=slide_]'),
    i = 0,
    len = $els.length;

$els.slice(1).hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn();
    })
}, 20000) });
```

It work just fine. the problem I am having is that whene it slides to next street camera it takes a fue secends to load the stream.

I am trying to figure out how a can fadeIn the next camera will delay the fadeOut for 5 sec so that next camera can "preload" before previous camera fadeOut

Any ideas how i can solve this?

PS: Sorry for the bad English

Comment: I am not surt, but try: $els.eq(i).fadeIn(5000); instead of $els.eq(i).fadeIn();

Comment: I tried that only delays the fade in and gives me a blank screen for 5sec befor loading next camera

Comment: maybe you can load the next camera stream in a hidden div before you start the fadeout. Then it will be cached and should appear quickly?

Comment: Problem with that is i have 5 cameras in Full HD and thats a lott of Bandwidth and CPU resources being consumed to preload all the cameras at the same time

Comment: You don't need to preload all the images, just the next one, keep loading the next image and sliding it until you've loaded all of them.

Comment: Are the streams iframes?

Comment: they are in object

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved my problem I was having.
Now I have a new problem I am getting a flicker when changing from one video to the next

Her is my code, probably not the most elegant code but it work's

```
$("#slideshow > span:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > span:first')
    .delay().css({'display':'inline'})    
    .delay().css({'opacity':'1',}).animate({'opacity': 0}, 3000)
    .next()  
    .delay().css({'opacity':'0',}).animate({'opacity': 1}, 3000)
    .delay().css({'display':'inline'})        
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 10000);

setInterval(function() {
  $('span:nth-child(2)')
    .delay().css({'display':'inline','opacity':'0',})       
    .end()
}, 10000);

setInterval(function() {
  $('span:nth-last-child(2)')
    .delay().css({'display':'none','opacity':'0',})       
    .end()
}, 10000);
```

Any ideas on how i can remove the flicker when Transaction from one video to the next?